# How do I fix a reverse error in Django when redirecting?

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a website where you can create a shopping list. I am trying to insert items into the shoplist. So things like banana, cake, etc would go into shoplist. I got everything to work. When I create the item, it goes inside the database but when I try to redirect back to the website where I pressed ***create item***, it shows the error

***Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shoplist/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$']***

Also, when I try to enter my details page, it shows the error

**Reverse for 'createitem' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shoplist/(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/createitem/$']**

I think I did something wrong when making my paths or doing something wrong syntax wise. Nothing I found on the internet is fixing it. Is there a way to fix this problem? Thank you very much!

views.py

```
def createitem(request, item_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'shoplist/createitem.html', {'form':ItemForm(), 'id':item_id})
    else:
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        itemlist = form.save(commit=False)
        itemlist.shoplist = Shoplist.objects.filter(user=request.user, pk=item_id).first()
        itemlist.user = request.user
        itemlist.save()
        return redirect('detail', pk=item_id)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from shoplist import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    #authentication
    path('signup/', views.usersignup, name='usersignup'),
    path('logout/', views.userlogout, name='userlogout'),
    path('login/', views.userlogin, name='userlogin'),
    path('create/', views.createlist, name='createlist'),
    path('shoplist/', views.currentshoplist, name='currentshoplist'),
    path('shoplist/<int:item_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('shoplist/<int:item_id>/createitem/', views.createitem, name='createitem'),
]
```

detail.html

```
{% extends 'shoplist/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2>{{ error }}</h2>
<h1>{{ shopitems }}</h1>
{% for i in item %}
{{i.item}}
{% endfor %}

<form action="{% url 'createitem' item_id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Create Item</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to redirect to the `'detail'` view and the arg required for it is `item_id` as an int.  I think you want `redirect('detail', item_id=item_id)`.  However, you probably want to get the created `pk` from the form...  Maybe `form.instance.pk`?  So `redirect('detail', item_id=form.instance.pk)`.  It's not clear if that form is for saving the same object type as you're viewing with the 'detail' view.

For the `{% url %}`, I don't think you can use anything but keyword args.  So, `{% url 'createitem' item_id=item_id %}` if you put `item_id` into the template context.

Comment: redirect('detail', item_id=item_id) worked thank you! How would I direct to createitem.html in the form section of detail.html? I think I need to pass through the item id for that as well but I can't figure out the syntax for it

Comment: Ah, I figured it out! I had to render item_id in the dictionary inside the detail function! Thanks for the help!

Comment: ...edited the answer, but I guess you figured that part out yourself.  cheers!